# If I create a table from view in Oracle, will this table data be updated along with the view?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I used below query to create the table from view:

create table <table_name> as (select * from <View_name> where column1 not in ());

Answer (score 0):

No.  The table is a new table with data that, after creation, is disconnected from the source.